# Substitute repeating words

Tags: align, substitution

I have several equations where some text repeats, so I want to match each following word with a "»" in next equations. Important that "»" should be in the middle of the word above.

Here is the demo example I made in an image editor.
[image]

Comment: There is a question (and answers) about this somewhere on the site already

Comment: @cgnieder could you privide me with the link? Can't find anything like that.

Comment: I haven't found it, either. I just remembered that there was a question before

Comment: @JairoADelRio, thank you, exactly what I was looking for.